# Can't use HDFS path to set_tracking_uri in mlflow within python

Tags: python, mlflow

I'm new to mlflow so I may misunderstand how things are supposed to work on a fundamental level.

However when I try to do the following:

```py
TRACKING_URI = os.path.join(
    "hdfs://namenode/user/userid/",
    "mlflow",
    "anomaly_detection",
)
        
mlflow.set_tracking_uri(TRACKING_URI)
client = mlflow.tracking.MlflowClient(TRACKING_URI)
```

I get the following error:

```sh
UnsupportedModelRegistryStoreURIException:  Model registry functionality is unavailable; got unsupported URI 'hdfs://nameservice1/user/rxb427/mlflow/anomaly_detection' for model registry data storage. Supported URI schemes are: ['', 'file', 'databricks', 'http', 'https', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite', 'mssql']. See https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/tracking.html#storage for how to run an MLflow server against one of the supported backend storage locations.
```

Within the above link provided by the error it states that hdfs is supported. Bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. So it looks like while the ARTIFACTS STORE does support hdfs, you have to use either file or a sql like for the BACKEND STORE.

Comment: maybe this post can assist https://medium.com/@moyukh_51433/mlflow-storing-artifacts-in-hdfs-and-in-an-sqlite-db-7be26971b6ab

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we support multiple kinds of storage for both [artifacts and MLflow entities](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/tracking.html#storage).

You can choose to use your default-root-artifact-store as hdfs and your back-end-store as an SQLAlchemy compatible database. Supply those arguments as part of

`mlflow server --default-root-artifact-store URI --backend-store URI --host 0.0.0.0

In your MLfow clien code set:
mlflow.set_tracking_uri(host_uri)